# How to set a cell delegate when configuring a cell with RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource

Tags: rx-swift

I have a delegate method that I want to execute when  button in a cell is tapped. I configured my cell using RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource and when I set the delegate here it it says they are unrelated types which I don't understand because my viewController inherits the delegate and implements its method.

```
let notificationsDataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionOfCustomData>(
        configureCell: {dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewNotificationTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? NewNotificationTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.configureCell(item: item, indePath: indexPath)
            cell.notificationDeleteDelegate = self
            return cell
    })
```

> I get this error "Cannot assign value of type
>   '(NotificationViewController) -> () -> NotificationViewController' to
>   type 'TableViewCellDeleteDelegate?'"

Answer (score 0):

Seems that NotificationViewController is not conform to TableViewCellDeleteDelegate...

```
extension NotificationViewController: TableViewCellDeleteDelegate {
   // TableViewCellDeleteDelegate Methods here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
extension NotificationViewController {

    func setupTableView() {

        let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<NotificationSectionModel>(
            configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cellidentifier, for: indexPath) as! NotificationCellCell
                cell.configure(title: item, indexPath: indexPath, viewModel: self.viewModel)
                return cell
        })

        viewModel.sections
            .asDriver()
            .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            >>> bag

        tableView
            .rx.setDelegate(self)
            >>> bag
    }
}
```

and then in your cell class use this for binding

```
        func configure(title: String, indexPath: IndexPath, viewModel: YourViewModel) {

            setupBinding(section: indexPath.section, viewModel: viewModel)
            }

        private func setupBinding(section: Int, viewModel: YourViewModel) {
    }
```